# Python - Solve for unknown value so that column minimum is equal to certain number

Tags: python, pandas, loops, solver

I have a dataframe, where column B is an equation of value in column A and an unknown value x, eg. B= A^x. I would like to solve x, so that the minimum of column B is equal to certain number, say 0.001. It's easy to solve in Excel, but wondering how to solve this in python?? Thanks!

My thoughts are like below, but it doesnt work...

```
import sympy as sym

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    x = sym.symbols('x')
    row['B'] = row['A']**x
    f = sym.Eq(row['B'].min(), 0.001)
    sym.solve(f,x)
```

Comment: `np.polyfit(df['A'], np.log(df['B']))`?

Comment: Try removing the `.min()`? Also, you better do something with the result of the `sym.solve`. either print it or set it to your dataframe.